# Why do hemorrhoid medicines include moisturisers such as Witch's Hazel and Aloe Vera?

Tags: medications, home-remedy

I read that Witch's Hazel is good as home remedy for hemorrhoid nodules and that it is sometimes a component of medicines. But Witch's Hazel creams are generally intended for the face. So what is the deal with that?

Comment: I found a source that says that Witch's Hazel has never confirmed in large scale trials but it contains tannic acid has shown some constrictive action on blood vessels. Also Witch's Hazel has proven general safety.